# Html 5 audio tag custom controls?

Tags: html, html5-audio

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills here because I can not figure out how to render the html 5 audio tag with custom controls.

I have this html so far, and it works no problem:

```
<audio controls preload='none'><source src='the url to the audio' type='audio/wav' /></audio>
```

How do I get it to display ONLY the play button, and perhaps when playing, show the pause button in it's place.

From what I read,

> By default, the element will not expose any sort of player controls.
>   You can create your own controls with plain old HTML, CSS, and
>   JavaScript. The element has methods like play() and pause() and a
>   read/write property called currentTime. There are also read/write
>   volume and muted properties. So you really have everything you need to
>   build your own interface.
>
> If you don’t want to build your own interface, you can tell the
>   browser to display a built-in set of controls. To do this, just
>   include the controls attribute in your tag.

But I can not find any examples of using custom controls. How do you get just the play button?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You create your elements like so...

```
<audio id="yourAudio" preload='none'>
    <source src='the url to the audio' type='audio/wav' />
</audio>
<a href="#" id="audioControl">play!</a>
```

And add some functionality:

```
var yourAudio = document.getElementById('yourAudio'),
    ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl');

ctrl.onclick = function () {

    // Update the Button
    var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'pause!';
    ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'play!' : 'pause!';

    // Update the Audio
    var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
    yourAudio[method]();

    // Prevent Default Action
    return false;
};
```

Right now, the button is just simple text ("play!" or "pause!"), but you could do just about anything you wanted with CSS. Instead of setting the `innerHTML`, set the `className` and you're good to go!

Comment: @AdilMalik Change audio link dropbox.

Comment: Hi, Actually I was looking into google dictionary, what I mean by that is when I suppose search "define hello", a dictionary appear on google, which also has audio icon, when I click that, audio plays, but it does not have any controls, I thought they maybe using something like what your answer propose, the audio starts when I click the audio icon, which is an input element, but I could not find any click event associated with it, that triggers the audio, I am confused

Answer (score 12):

After a lot of research, I found an easy way of eliminating and manipulating specific parts of the predefined controls.

Create your elements as you usually would, like so:

```html
<audio autoPlay>
    <source src='audioUrl' type='audio/mpeg' />
</audio>
```

Then in the CSS file, you write the following:

```css
/* Specifies the size of the audio container */
audio {
  width: 115px;
  height: 25px;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  height: 25px;
}

/* Removes the timeline */
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
  display: none !important;
}

/* Removes the time stamp */
audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {
  display: none;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {
  display: none;
}
```

With this code, you should get a small and nice looking container with only mute-button, pause/play-button and the 'download-file'-tag.

For an overview of all the things you can modify, have a look [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-1889.1/css/mediaControls.css.auto.html).

The following code will also remove the mute- and the play-button:

```css
/* Removes mute-button */
audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {
  display: none;
}

/* Removes play-button */
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have been experimenting with the use of a graphic instead of the player.  Set the style within the 'audio' tag to "display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;" (display none does not work on iPad, thus the additional width-0 and height-0 settings).  Also not including the "controls" attribute should work. (different systems/browsers & desktop vs iOS all act differently.....)

Eg:

```
<head>
<script>
function EvalSound(soundobj) {
  var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
  thissound.play();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
Click the speaker to hear the sound.  <a href="javascript:null()" onClick="EvalSound('sound1'); return false;">
<img src="sound_icon.png" alt="" title="sound_icon" width="" height="" class="" /></a>
<audio id="sound1" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;" src="sound.mp3" controls preload="auto" autobuffer>
</body>
```

The "javascript:null()" works on iPad in conjunction with "return false;" as opposed to the usual "#".

For more really useful information:
http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play.htm

Comment: You don't have to set the style to "display: none;". If you look you have a "controls" tag. This serves as a boolean to designate whether the player is shown or not. Just get rid of that and you won't have to include any inline css.

Comment: Sadly the 'more really useful information' link above appears to be broken, target evaporated.

Answer (score 4):

if you want the built-in play-button only you could:

use autio-tag's class attribute:

```
 <audio controls preload='auto' class="audio_volume_only"><source src='the url to the 
audio' type='audio/mp3' /></audio>
```

and fit the css:

```
 .audio_volume_only {
    width: 35px;
  }
```

i hoped [controls](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#controls) has some parameters, [but not found any or misunderstood](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#the-audio-element) .. we'll see.

then possibly use [audio's onplay - event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664409/html5-lazy-onplay-event-handler-for-audio-tag) to change the css to your need.
the play-button will become the pause-button in built-in controls

as others pointed out, you can always make your own....