# Remove mute/volume bar from standard Html5 audio player?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Given the standard html5 audio player,

HTML:

```
<audio controls></audio>
```

([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o6TN.png))

Is there a way to remove only the "mute" button and volume slider?  I'd like to keep the play/pause button and the track-position slider.

Answer (score 5):

To change these you can use some crafty **CSS**. With the border radius altered on the right hand side this looks like what you are after.

[image]

See this js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3j76551r/1/

```
 div {
    width: 260px;
    overflow: hidden;
    direction: ltl;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.5em 0.5em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em 0.7em;
}
```

Another option would be the javascript option. This would be to write your own player using the html audio element. There is a really good tutorial [here](http://www.alexkatz.me/html5-audio/building-a-custom-html5-audio-player-with-javascript/) that I have done in the past that teaches you how to write your own player with javascript.

Comment: There is also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51644040/4934640 `audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button { display: none !important; } audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider { display: none !important; }`

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve this by manipulating the css, specific to the audio tag. This way, you can remove and modify elements related to the controls container. Please have a look here for further details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64012853/13334628