# Audio tag without a volume slider or mute button?

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-audio

I created an audio tag without a download button with

```
<audio controls controlslist="nodownload">
```

This was successful.

Now, how do I remove the volume slider (plus mute button) that comes up when I play the sound?

I tried

```
<audio controls controlslist="novolume">
```

without any luck.

[image: result]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new `controlslist` attribute in the [HTML5 standard](https://wicg.github.io/controls-list/html-output/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-media-controlslist) can only accept three settings:

```
"nodownload", "nofullscreen" and "noremoteplayback".
```

There are none to control specific controls beside from that. The only (current) workaround for this is to build your own custom interface for the audio object and provide only the controls you want the user to access via the UI.

The attribute is currently only supported in Chrome and Opera, as well as Android. This of course being another incentive to build a custom UI for the audio (or use a library as suggested by Johannes).

Comment: Did not find that site when googling!

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {
    display: none !important;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the HTML5 `audio` tag there is only `controls` or nothing, and each browser will display it a little differently. But there is not way to have only some of the controls displayed.

To achieve that, you'd have to use a javascript/jQuery player like `jPlayer` ( http://jplayer.org/) that allows  complete individual cofiguration of the UI (but still uses HTML5 in the background).

Comment: But `controlslist="nodownload"` was successfully removing the download button, which should be a contradiction to `controls` to be the only available attribute.

Comment: There is no download button in an HTML5 tag

Comment: You see it in my screenshot.

Comment: Look at these screenshots of the HTML5 audio player in the most common browsers: https://html5tutorial.info/html5-audio.php Your screenshot is definitely something else, but not a default HTML5 audio element.

Comment: You have an almost identical screenshot of the player on that page.

Comment: but only almost: There is no download button

Comment: anyway, maybe the first one (which is not a screenshot but the way your browser displays it): which browser are you using? As you can see, the screenshots below that have no download button

Comment: I have one in the first player on that page, the one actually being rendered by an audio tag. So what you say is that its not the player of google chrome, but some add-on?

Comment: It seems that Chrome is the only browser that shows the download button. Chrome is the only browser that shows the download button. It has supported controlsList="nodownload" since Chrome 55.

Comment: well, a download button definitely is not standard in an HTML5 audio player, but rather the exception. But as I wrote, there is jPlayer if you need more flexibility, and that will look exactly the same in *every* browser.