# Why can't the seeking attribute work on the chrome browser..?? it works on IE however

Tags: python, django

my model code is like this

```
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(contentType, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    content_subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    content_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    upload_content = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

this is what i have on my view 
but bk = Content.objects.get(id=id) how i acquired my video content from database to site
then to template

```
    list_of_subjects = Subject.objects.filter(grade=grade_id)
    subject_video = contentType.objects.filter(content_types = 'SubjectVideos')
    subject_video_list = Content.objects.filter(content_type__in=subject_video)

    bk = Content.objects.get(id=id)

    context={
        'list_of_subjects':list_of_subjects,
        'subject_video_list':subject_video_list,
        'bk': bk

    }
    return render(request,'bgcse/bgcse_subject_video_list.html',context)
```

then i have used this video tag on my html template
the class video-fluid and etc only takes care of the video sizes and margins etc

the video plays and works just fine, the only problem is seeking on chrome

````
<video class="video-fluid z-depth-1" autoplay controlsList="nodownload"  controlsList="seeking">
<source src="{{bk.upload_content.url}}">
</video>
{% endblock %} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Since chrome made `HTML5` as default over `Flash` ([article](https://www.engadget.com/2016/12/02/google-chrome-html5-default/))

You can only use 3 types of attributes on `controlsList` [docs](https://wicg.github.io/controls-list/html-output/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-media-controlslist)

These 3 are:

```
"nodownload", "nofullscreen" and "noremoteplayback".
```

You can use custom attributes if you want following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48333012/11225821)

Comment: with those controls the seek attribute still doesn't work