# Hide progressbar from <audio> HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I am working on a game in which I want background music playing. I was wondering if there was a way to hide the progress bar of the music and only display the play and stop button with  the volume slider?

Right now I have resized the width so that the play button will only show, but when I change it to a bigger width to have the slider show, the progressbar comes back out. I want to get rid of the progress bar completely.

Comment: I would suggest you to hide entire `audio` element and use custom controls over `audio` element..[This](http://codesamplez.com/programming/control-html5-audio-with-jquery) may help..

Comment: Thanks @RayonDabre , I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to pick and choose which controls you want in HTML5.  If you don't want to use the full set of default audio player controls, you'll have to make your own set of controls instead of using the browser default ones. 
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638754/html-5-audio-tag-custom-controls) for more details on creating your own and accessing the DOM API for audio elements.

Comment: Alright thanks! I'll Google a bit and see if I can figure out how to make my own control.