# Simply using the <audio></audio> tag and want it to be customized in mobile platforms

Tags: html, css, ionic3

How can i customize the css of html audio control (to work on mobile platforms) ? " audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel" it just work in browser i want it to be customized in ionic app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the controls for the `<audio>` element and add manually your own customized controls to control the audio element.

That is removing the `controls` attribute and adding links and buttons and associate javascript functionality to manage (play/stop/progress...) the audio

Here is some about declaring the `<audio>`element https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp

And this answers shows you a little example how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/7639343/4635829