# Replace icon in mobile version of web site

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a block with audio track and I want replace all track with one play/stop icon. How can I do that?

```css
.lesson-item {
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: transform 300ms linear 0ms, box-shadow 300ms linear 0ms, z-index 300ms linear 0ms;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform-origin: left top;
}

.lesson-item:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
    
.img {
    background-size: cover;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: height 300ms, width 300ms;
    transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div class="lesson-item">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff)"></div>
    <div class="description">
        <div class="player">
            <audio preload="auto" controls>
                <source src="assets/audio.mp3" />
                <source src="assets/audio.ogg" />
                <source src="assets/audio.wav" />
            </audio>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <a href="#">Text</a>
        <a href="#">Text</a>
        <a href="#">Text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to have just one icon play/stop instead of all track.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html 5 audio tag custom controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638754/html-5-audio-tag-custom-controls)

Comment: about the duplicate link: all you need to do is to remove `controls` from the audio tag and manually trigger play/pause from your cusom element listener

Comment: @Kaddath it is not a duplicate. this is another question. could you show it on my sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/laberg/jhugx58y/22/

```js
function togglePlay(video) {

  var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
  
  if (audio) {
  
    if (audio.paused) {
     audio.play();
        document.getElementById("button").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149658.svg";
    } else {
     audio.pause();
        document.getElementById("button").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149657.svg";
    }
  
  }
}
```

```css
.lesson-item {
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: transform 300ms linear 0ms, box-shadow 300ms linear 0ms, z-index 300ms linear 0ms;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform-origin: left top;
}

.lesson-item:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
    
.img {
    background-size: cover;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: height 300ms, width 300ms;
    transform-origin: left top;
}
#button {
  width:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lesson-item">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff)"></div>
    <div class="description">
        <div class="player">
            <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149657.svg" onclick="togglePlay(this)" id="button">
            <audio preload="auto">
                <source src="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mp3/bachfugue.mp3" />
                <source src="assets/audio.ogg" />
                <source src="assets/audio.wav" />
            </audio>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <a href="#">Text</a>
        <a href="#">Text</a>
        <a href="#">Text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you tell why do we need `[0]` in js code? I mean what is the purpose of this chunk of code? Thank you.

Comment: No problem. It is a way of accessing elements on your page. The getElementsByTagName('audio') method returns all the elements with the <audio> tag. And since I know there is only one audio, I take it directly with the index 0. But a better way to do this is to give your audio a specific id like this: <audio id="audio"> and access it with getElementById("audio") without the [0].